# PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'D_DEPT_ID' in toad

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created procedure with substitution variable in Toad for Oracle but its giving me error

"PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'D_DEPT_ID'"

**Procedure Code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_dept
IS

dept_id dept.deptno%TYPE;
dept_name dept.dname%TYPE;

BEGIN
dept_id := :d_dept_id;
dept_name := ':d_ name';

INSERT INTO dept(deptno,dname) VALUES (dept_id,dept_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' INSERTED ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' ROW ');
END;
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Why don't you use procedure parameters and accept user input while invoking the procedure?

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak i want user enter values at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot place bind variables inside of procedure or function code. To accomplish your task, you must pass the values in as parameters of the procedure at runtime.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_dept(dept_id dept.deptno%TYPE, dept_name dept.dname%TYPE) IS

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dept(deptno,dname) VALUES (dept_id,dept_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' INSERTED ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' ROW '); 
END;
```

Then at runtime, in your anonymous block or calling code, you pass the values in from the end user..

```
BEGIN
   add_date(:d_dept_id, :d_dept_name);
END;
```